# Segmentation fault in multi-json-1.8.4 during heroku fork, database transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, fork

I'm trying to **heroku fork** a RoR 4.0.1 app to make a dev instance. It creates the instance OK but core dumps during the database transfer, details below.

Running on Lubuntu, Heroku Toolbelt version is 3.5.0 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3

I tried with system ruby at 1.9.3, ditched that leaving 2.0.0 and still the same. I can manually copy the database to workaround this, but forking would be so much quicker. Is there a bug here, or some update I can do?

```
Creating fork my-manager-dev... done
Copying slug... done
Adding papertrail:choklad... done
Adding pgbackups:plus... done
Adding heroku-postgresql:dev... done
Transferring database (this can take some time)... /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapters/yajl.rb:11: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0021 p:---- s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 CFUNC  :parse
c:0020 p:0044 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapters/yajl.rb:11
c:0019 p:0062 s:0098 b:0098 l:000097 d:000097 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:20
c:0018 p:0035 s:0093 b:0093 l:000092 d:000092 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json.rb:120
c:0017 p:0019 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:184
c:0016 p:0044 s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb:36
c:0015 p:0018 s:0077 b:0077 l:000056 d:000076 BLOCK  /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:147
c:0014 p:---- s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 CFUNC  :loop
c:0012 p:0226 s:0070 b:0070 l:000056 d:000069 BLOCK  /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:146
c:0011 p:0077 s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:222
c:0010 p:0018 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:131
c:0009 p:0322 s:0049 b:0049 l:000035 d:000048 BLOCK  /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:80
c:0008 p:---- s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 CFUNC  :each
c:0006 p:0244 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:55
c:0005 p:0046 s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:218
c:0004 p:0112 s:0014 b:0014 l:000013 d:000013 METHOD /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28
c:0003 p:0234 s:0008 b:0008 l:00155c d:001d2c EVAL   /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:00155c d:00155c TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:25:in `<main>'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:55:in `index'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:80:in `block in index'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:131:in `migrate_db'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:222:in `action'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:146:in `block in migrate_db'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:146:in `loop'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/fork.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in migrate_db'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb:36:in `get_transfer'
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:184:in `json_decode'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json.rb:120:in `load'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:20:in `load'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapters/yajl.rb:11:in `load'
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/multi_json-1.8.4/lib/multi_json/adapters/yajl.rb:11:in `parse'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x15b433) [0xb7644433] time.c:4400
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x4dedf) [0xb7536edf] dir.c:1065
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_bug+0x40) [0xb75374b0] dir.c:1263
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0xf5d0c) [0xb75ded0c] range.c:971
[0xb770940c]
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/libruby.so.2.0(+0x7f4b6) [0xb6ab54b6] gc.c:637
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/libruby.so.2.0(rb_newobj_of+0x1b) [0xb6ab59db] gc.c:687
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/libruby.so.2.0(rb_float_new_in_heap+0x2f) [0xb6aee56f] numeric.c:640
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0/lib/yajl/yajl.so(+0x2841) [0xb6d18841] /home/nathaniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:832
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0/lib/yajl/yajl.so(+0x464e) [0xb6d1a64e] yajl_parser.c:258
/home/nathaniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/yajl-ruby-1.2.0/lib/yajl/yajl.so(+0x21fc) [0xb6d181fc] yajl_ext.c:254
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145c91) [0xb762ec91] string.c:1425
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x154cb7) [0xb763dcb7] string.c:8287
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ba5e) [0xb7634a5e] string.c:1743
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x150158) [0xb7639158] string.c:3636
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x1554d7) [0xb763e4d7] string.c:8360
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_rescue2+0x173) [0xb753b473] enum.c:1282
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x146092) [0xb762f092] string.c:5640
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145c75) [0xb762ec75] string.c:1428
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x154cb7) [0xb763dcb7] string.c:8287
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ba5e) [0xb7634a5e] string.c:1743
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x150158) [0xb7639158] string.c:3636
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_yield+0x180) [0xb763f9f0] struct.c:530
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_ary_each+0x54) [0xb7506ac4] encoding.c:1184
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x145c75) [0xb762ec75] string.c:1428
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x154cb7) [0xb763dcb7] string.c:8287
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x14ba5e) [0xb7634a5e] string.c:1743
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x150158) [0xb7639158] string.c:3636
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(rb_iseq_eval_main+0xac) [0xb764090c] struct.c:988
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(+0x5144c) [0xb753a44c] enum.c:593
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(ruby_exec_node+0x24) [0xb753af84] enum.c:1449
/usr/lib/libruby-1.9.1.so.1.9(ruby_run_node+0x36) [0xb753c996] enum.c:2324
ruby1.9.1() [0x8048678]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0xb73574d3]
ruby1.9.1() [0x80486a1]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug with JSON lib change in Heroku lib: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1048#issuecomment-37778081